# Good off topic questions: migrate rather than close?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, migration

This [question was closed as off topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141031/how-do-i-format-an-ssd-to-be-used-as-the-hibernation-drive-acer-s3) and the original poster was asked to crosspost. As far as I can tell, diamond moderators have the ability to move posts from one site to another – in this case from Ask Ubuntu to Superuser. I've noticed we can flag to move to specific sites as well.

It's unusual, since all the SE sites are linked and moving the question is a more efficient way of handling this than closing and asking to crosspost.

Could we have the mods here move posts appropriately rather than closing them?

Answer (score 8):

We can and we do.

In this case I was in the middle of contacting the mods on the other site to see if they wish to take it.  We tend to close – ask – and then migrate if necessary.

There is a judgment call as to what is "good to migrate" and what is "not good to migrate".  Ask Ubuntu mods cannot generally make this call unless they have some expertise.

Other sites do not like it if we automatically migrate incomplete questions or questions that are not really a good fit for their site - thus we need the mods on other sites and the community here to help out.

This is where the Ask Ubuntu community could help – they can flag or drop comments if they recognise it is a valid fit for a particular site.

Hope this explains how we migrate questions.

Comment: If a question is good enough for another site, then whether it's crap or not depends honestly on the user. If the user has a vested interest in the question they'll want to take the few minutes to copy the question over. Yes we can migrate, but it's really a feature for corner cases.

Answer (score 3):

### Migration process to another site:

1. Close question in Ask Ubuntu
2. Go for coffee so you don't make quick judgements over the post
3. Look at the post again and judge the level of interest and quality
4. If it looks good contact the mods on the sites you think that post can fit and ask them if they are interested in having it migrated there
5. Go for another coffee and wait for reactions from mods
6. Migrate if good, don't do anything if mods are not interested

#### Only rule here is: **don't migrate unnecessary crap to other sites.**

Since we are not experts on all other sites in SE we need to have some feedback from people that take care of them, ie: *would hate to migrate a gardening question to cooking or SciFi when it obviously was math related :/*

Things happen, you just need to be patient.